# Using basic joins in sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, sequel

I'm using the `sequel` gem in Ruby to connect to a sqlite database (provided by rails). I have various `User`s and various `Project`s. I want to find the unique project object `user.username/project.name`, if it exists. What's the most elegant way of doing this? I have the connection working etc. I have:

```
DB = Sequel.connect 'sqlite:///path/to/sqlite'
class User < Sequel::Model
end

class Project < Sequel::Model
end

# How do I retrieve the project object using project_name, user_name
#   project.name == project_name
#   project.user_id = xxx
#   and there is a user with id xxx and username user_name?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the `project_name` and `user_name` and want to do a join and find the project that matches both:

```
Project.join(:users, :id=>:user_id).
 select(:projects.*).
 first(:users__name=>user_name, :projects__name=>project_name)
```